# Can I undo the effect of "using namespace" in C++?

Tags: c++, namespaces, using

With `using namespace` I make the whole contents of that namespace directly visible without using the namespace qualifier. This can cause problems if `using namespace` occurs in widely used headers - we can unintendedly make two namespaces with identical classes names visible and the compiler will refuse to compile unless the class name is prepended with the namespace qualifier.

Can I undo `using namespace` so that the compiler forgets that it saw it previously?

Comment: I bet there's a really ugly hack using the pre-processor for this. But I guess you don't want that

Comment: @Eli: There isn't in Boost, which probably means that there isn't one.

Comment: A possible solution to at least shorten what you have to type would be to `#define N namespace::` at the top of a file and `#undef N` at the bottom. Of course this then means you have to be careful to never use `N` anywhere in the file you don't want `namespace::` to be. A `typedef` could potentially be useful as well.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No, but you can tell your coworkers that you should never have a `using` directive or declaration in a header.

Comment: Unfortunately, a third party library (https://opencv.org/platforms/cuda.html) requires this and we cannot rewrite it. This does not look like an answer, many things should be avoided in the life but are inevitable.

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas being impractical doesn't make it incorrect.

Answer (score 16):

As others said, you can't and the problem shouldn't be there in the first place.
The next-best thing you can do is bring in your needed symbols so that they are preferred by the name look-up:

```
namespace A { class C {}; }
namespace B { class C {}; }
using namespace A;
using namespace B;

namespace D {
    using A::C; // fixes ambiguity
    C c;
}
```

In some cases you can also wrap the offending includes with a namespace:

```
namespace offender {
#  include "offender.h"
}
```

Comment: That last technique can be a can of worms. If offender.h includes headers that are `#define` protected, now those symbols are stuck in offender. You could try to put its entire interface package comprehensively in a new namespace, but still hope it doesn't include system headers. And if it works once, it might break in the next version.

Answer (score 7):

No, C++ Standard doesn't say anything about "undo". The best you are allowed to do is to limit scope of `using`:

```
#include <vector>

namespace Ximpl {

using namespace std;    
vector<int> x;

}

vector<int> z; // error. should be std::vector<int>
```

But unfortunately `using namespace Ximpl` will bring all names from `std` namespace as well.

Answer (score 3):

Not to my knowledge... But as a rule I only use "using namespace" in .cpp files.

Answer (score 1):

The closest, that I'll try to use in header files is following:

```
//example.h

#ifndef EXAMPLE_H_
#define EXAMPLE_H_


/**
 * hating c++ for not having "undo" of using namespace xx
 */
#define string std::string
#define map std::map

class Example {
public:
    Example (const char *filename);
    Example (string filename);
    ~Example ();
private:
    map<string,complicated_stuff*> my_complicated_map;

};

#undef string
#undef map

#endif //EXAMPLE_H_
```

after all, defines are #undef -able.
There are 2 problems:
1. it is ugly
2. separate #define and #undef for each name from the corresponding namespace are used

Answer (score 0):

As stated you should not use `using namespace sth` in header files. When you need functionality from a namespace in your implementation you can leverage scopes like this:

```
void func() {
    // some code agnostic to your namespace.
    {
        using namespace sth;
        // some code aware of sth.
    }
    // some other code agnostic to your namespace.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The thread is aged, though @rlbond might have separated "namespace declaration" from "using directive", so obviously I had to ponder here.
2. @Georg Fritzsche encourages toxic environ with naming his "offender". In the least, you found any work product something business-disagreeable.
3. Personally, I do not like sprinkling "std::" everywhere (it becomes a swarm of mosquitoes), though I agree with @rlbond with avoiding any *using namespace* clause within any header. Separating execution code away from header files (as: establishing a link library) is always good programming practice.

Comment: Rather than `using namespace std` just be selective: `using std::vector; using std::string;` and you'll be swatting many fewer mosquitoes.