# Can I avoid qualifying names defined by a specific class?

Tags: c++, class, enums, scope, naming

Suppose I have a MessageBox class along the following lines:

```
class MyMessageBox
{
public:
    enum Priority {
        Prior_Dialog,
        Prior_Warning,
        // ...
    };

    enum Icon {
        Icon_Question,
        Icon_Exclamation,
        // ...
    };

    enum Button {
        Button_Yes,
        Button_No,
        Button_Cancel,
        // ...
    };

    static void Show(Priority pPriority, Icon pIcon, Button pButton1, Button pButton2);

    // ...
};
```

Now, if I want to throw up a messagebox, I have to type out `MyMessageBox::` for every single identifier:

```
MyMessageBox::Show(MyMessageBox::Prior_Dialog, MyMessageBox::Icon_Question, MyMessageBox::Button_Yes, MyMessageBox::Button_No);
```

Ideally, I'd like some non-macro solution that will allow source files that `#include "MyMessageBox.h"` to omit the `MyMessageBox::` qualifications everywhere. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it would be convenient if the enumerations and the class are declared in the **separate** namespace (i.e. enumerations should be declared outside the class) just **not to pollute the global namespace**.

```
namespace MessageBoxUtils {

enum Priority {
    Prior_Dialog,
    Prior_Warning,
    // ...
};

enum Icon {
    Icon_Question,
    Icon_Exclamation,
    // ...
};

enum Button {
    Button_Yes,
    Button_No,
    Button_Cancel,
    // ...
};

class MyMessageBox
{
public:
    static void Show(Priority pPriority, Icon pIcon, Button pButton1, Button pButton2);

    // ...
};

} // namespace MessageBoxUtils
```

Client code (some cpp file):

```
#include ...

using namespace MessageBoxUtils;

...

void SomeClass::Foo()
{
    MyMessageBox::Show(Prior_Dialog, Icon_Question, ...);
}
```

Comment: Follow-up question: I know putting `using` declarations in header files is a big no-no in general, but in this case, would it be acceptable to put `using MessageBoxUtils` directly into `MyMessageBox.h`, so that it's automatically present in every source file that uses it?

Comment: @suszterpatt, `using namespace` statement in **header files** is a bad smell, but it is good in implementation (cpp) files. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872373/why-is-including-using-namespace-into-a-header-file-a-bad-idea-in-c

Answer (score 7):

Yes, and quite simple. If you don't want the `enum`s inside the class, well... don't define them inside the class.

```
enum Priority {
    Prior_Dialog,
    Prior_Warning,
    // ...
};

enum Icon {
    Icon_Question,
    Icon_Exclamation,
    // ...
};

enum Button {
    Button_Yes,
    Button_No,
    Button_Cancel,
    // ...
};

class MyMessageBox
{
public:
    static void Show(Priority pPriority, Icon pIcon, Button pButton1, Button pButton2);
// ...
};
```

Comment: Alternatively, only call them from within the class.

Comment: Clobbers the global namespace. Ever heard of `using`?

Comment: @user946850 there's no namespace here, just a class.

Comment: @user946850 and besides, **that's exactly what he's asking**. If he doesn't want to qualify usage, he wants a polluted namespace...

Comment: @user946850 also, please show us how you'd use `using` with stuff defined inside a `class`.

Comment: Indeed, I was misled by the first glance on the documentation. Still I don't consider this good style. Would un-downvote if you edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define the enums outside the class, and you alsio want to avoid repetitions and avoid the risk of enum names clashes, consider also the C++11 `enum class` possibility:

Re-elaborating Luchian Grigore sample

```
enum class Priority {
    Dialog,
    Warning,
    // ...
};

enum class Icon {
    Question,
    Exclamation,
    // ...
};

enum class Button {
    Yes,
    No,
    Cancel,
    // ...
};
```

You are now forced to use the enums by explicitly qualifying them, like `Button::Yes`, `Icon::Question` etc., and you are also forced to cast explicitly to int (no implicit conversions exist)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "import" identifiers into the global namespace by means of the `using` keyword:

```
using MyMessageBox::Prior_Dialog; // won't work
```

(The first glance on the documentation misled me: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/was37tzw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Still, I would recommend leaving the enums where they belong -- in the MessageBox class. This avoids confusion and ambiguities -- someone else could define the same enum item but assign it a different value, leading to a compilation error.

Alternatively, you could change the class into a namespace, and then "load" identifiers (or even the whole namespace, if you wish), using `using`.

Other possible shortcuts include:

- `typedef`ing the enum inside the `MessageBox` class to a short convenient identifier and use this as qualification (hacky)
- Copying individual constants into your namespace as they are required (cumbersome)
- ...?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to put your enum into completely different namespace related to your widget. `Qt` libraries do so for example. They put lots of enum in `Qt` namespace instead of putting them in the specific classes