# C++ Separate Implementation and header files

Tags: c++

I have been given an assignment to split up a program into different files. The assignment was: Each of the files should contain the following:
customers.h: should contain the definition of the customer structure and the declaration of print customers.
customers.cpp: should contain the implementation (or definition) for print customers.
exercise 1 5.cpp: should contain an include of customers.h and the main program.

Here is my code:

**customers.h**

```
#pragma once;

void print_customers(customer &head);

struct customer
{
string name;
customer *next;

};
```

**customers.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void print_customers(customer &head) 
{
customer *cur = &head;
while (cur != NULL)
{
    cout << cur->name << endl;
    cur = cur->next;

}

}
```

**exercise_1_5.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "customers.h"
using namespace std;

main()
{
    customer customer1, customer2, customer3;
    customer1.next = &customer2;
    customer2.next = &customer3;

    customer3.next = NULL;
    customer1.name = "Jack";
    customer2.name = "Jane";
    customer3.name = "Joe";
    print_customers(customer1);
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles and runs fine in a single program but when i try to split it up and compile with `g++ -o customers.cpp`

I receive this error

```
customers.cpp:4:22: error: variable or field ‘print_customers’ declared void
customers.cpp:4:22: error: ‘customer’ was not declared in this scope
customers.cpp:4:32: error: ‘head’ was not declared in this scope
```

Can anyone help, I am just a beginner with c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of changes that you need in `customers.h`.  See the comments in the code.

```
#pragma once;

#include <string>        // including string as it is referenced in the struct

struct customer
{
    std::string name;    // using std qualifer in header
    customer *next;
};

// moved to below the struct, so that customer is known about
void print_customers(customer &head);
```

You must then `#include "customers.h"` in `customers.cpp`.

Note how I didn't write `using namespace std` in the header file.  As this would import the `std` namespace into anything that included `customer.h`.  For more details see: [Why is including "using namespace" into a header file a bad idea in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872373/why-is-including-using-namespace-into-a-header-file-a-bad-idea-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

```
void print_customers(customer &head);
```

C++ compiler work in top to bottom approach. So, every type, identifier it sees at the point must be known to it.

The problem is that compiler doesn't know the type `customer` in the above statement. Try forward declaring the type before the function's forward declaration.

```
struct customer;
```

Or move the function forward declaration after the struct definition.

Answer (score 2):

First,

```
#include "customers.h"  // in the "customers.cpp" file.
```

Second, `print_customers` uses `customer`, but this type is not declared yet. You have two ways to fix the problem.

1. Put declaration of the function after declaration of the struct.
2. Put a forwarded declaration (`struct customer;`) before declaration of the function,