# Calling virtual function - segmentation fault

Tags: c++, runtime-error, virtual

The way the code works is that there is a base pure virtual class called "Module" with subclasses of "Living", "Manufacturing" and "PowerGen" which uses some of the virtual functions. In the main driver file, I am successfully able to read a list of modules from a file and store them in a vector of Module pointers. The problem comes when I want to use the virtual display function to display that vectors element's module details. I am faced with a segmentation fault. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
Class Module
{
public:
   Module() = default;
   explicit Module(const string& purpose, const string& id)
   {
      this->purpose = purpose;
      this->id = id;
   }
   explicit Module(const string& purpose) { this->purpose = purpose; }
   virtual ~Module() { }

   virtual void setCrew( ) = 0;
   virtual void display( ) const = 0;
   void addCrew(const string& name)
   {
      crew_list.push_back(Crew(name));
      ++number_of_crew;
   }
   void setPowerReq(double power) { this->power = power; }
   void setMaxCrew(int max_crew) { this->max_crew = max_crew; }

   string getPurpose( ) { return purpose; }
   string getId( ) { return id; }
   int getNumberOfCrew( ) { return number_of_crew; }
   int getMaxCrew( ) { return max_crew; }
   double getPower( ) { return power; }

   friend ostream& operator << ( ostream& os, const Module& m );
   friend ofstream& operator << ( ofstream& os, const Module& m );
   friend ifstream& operator >> ( ifstream& is, Module& m );

private:
   string purpose = "unknown";
   string id = "unknown";
   int number_of_crew = 0;
   int max_crew = 0;
   double power = 0;
   vector<Crew> crew_list;
}; 


 class Living : public Module
{
public :

   Living( ) = default;
   explicit Living(const string& purpose);
   Living(int meals, const string& id);
   void setCrew( )
   {
      setMaxCrew( floor(meals / 3) );
      setPowerReq( meals * 1.4 );
   }
   void display( ) const
   {
      cout << *this;
   }

   friend ofstream& operator << ( ofstream& os, const Living& l );
   friend ifstream& operator >> ( ifstream& is, Living& l );

private :
   int meals = 0;
   static string type;
};

class Manufacturing : public Module
{
public:
   Manufacturing( ) = default;
   Manufacturing( const string& product, int quantity, const string& id );
   explicit Manufacturing( const string& purpose );
   void setCrew( )
   {
      setPowerReq( quantity * 6 );
      setMaxCrew( maxCrew );
   }
   void display( ) const
   {
      cout << *this;
   }

   friend ofstream& operator << ( ofstream& os, const Manufacturing& m );
   friend ifstream& operator >> ( ifstream& is, Manufacturing& m );

private:
   static string type;
   string product = "unknown";
   static int maxCrew;
   int quantity = 0;
};

class PowerGen : public Module
{
public:
   PowerGen() = default;
   PowerGen( int number_of_generators, const string& id );
   explicit PowerGen( const string& purpose );
   void setCrew( )
   {
      setMaxCrew(0);
      setPowerReq( -(number_of_generators * 7) );
   }
   void display( ) const
   {
      cout << *this;
   }

   friend ofstream& operator << ( ofstream& os, const PowerGen& p );
   friend ifstream& operator >> ( ifstream& is, PowerGen& p );

private:
   static string type;
   const int max_generators = 8;
   int number_of_generators = 0;
};
```

Portion relevant from the main driver file which when called causes the segmenation fault:

```
if( cityVector.size() > 0 )
   {
      cout << "\nHere is the complete City" << endl;
      for ( auto iter : cityVector )
      {
         iter->display( );
         cout << endl << endl;
      }
   } else {
      cout << "\nThere are no Modules in the City" << endl;
   }
```

This is how I loaded the data from a file, where VMOD = vector:

```
void load( VMOD & cityVector )
{
   string filename;
   cout << "Please enter a filename >> ";
   getline( cin, filename );
   ifstream fin;
   fin.open(filename);
   if (!fin.fail())
   {
      while ( !fin.eof() )
      {
         string purpose;
         getline( fin, purpose );
         if ( purpose == "Living" )
         {
            Living object(purpose);
            loadObject( cityVector, object, fin );
          } else if ( purpose == "Manufacturing" )
         {
            Manufacturing object(purpose);
            loadObject( cityVector, object, fin );
         } else if ( purpose == "Power Generation" )
         {
            PowerGen object(purpose);
            loadObject( cityVector, object, fin );
         } else {

         }
      }
      cout << "The city has " << cityVector.size() << " modules!" << endl;
   } else {
      cout << "File does not exist... " << endl;
   }
   fin.close();
}

template<typename T>
void loadObject( VMOD & cityVector, T object, ifstream& fin )
{
   fin >> object;
   Module* mptr;
   mptr = &object;
   cityVector.push_back(mptr);
}
```

With the file looking like this:

```
Living
L1
5
21
2
First Person
Fourth Person
15
Manufacturing
M1
10
12
4
Second Person
Third Person
Fifth Person
Sixth Person
C++ ness
2
Power Generation
P1
0
-14
0
2
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: The culprit, most likely, is the code you use to save the objects to the file and to read them from the file. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: You have all of these classes, yet you failed to show us anything that instantiates and exercises any of these classes.

Comment: 1) What is `cityVector`?  2) You shouldn't place `using namespace std;` in header files.

Comment: cityVector is a vector of Module pointers. I do have namespace std in the header files.

Comment: You should not be having `using namespace std;` in header files.  There are plenty of links saying why this is not a habit to get into.  Please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872373/why-is-including-using-namespace-into-a-header-file-a-bad-idea-in-c)

Comment: You need to read [this, about `eof`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: Don't vandalise your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a dangling pointer problem.

```
template<typename T>
void loadObject( VMOD & cityVector, T object, ifstream& fin )
{
   // object is a function local object
   // since it is passed by value.
   fin >> object;
   Module* mptr;

   // This is a pointer to a local object.
   // It is invalid when the function returns.
   mptr = &object;

   // Storing a pointer that will be a dangling pointer as soon
   // the function returns.
   cityVector.push_back(mptr);
}
```

You need to use dynamically allocated memory for the restored objects and save them in `cityVector`.

You'll need to make sure that memory is deallocated once you are done using it.

```
template<typename T>
void loadObject(VMOD& cityVector, ifstream& fin )
{
   T* objectPtr = new T;
   fin >> *objectPtr;
   cityVector.push_back(objectPtr);
}
```

and call it using the following syntax:

```
loadObject<LivingObject>(cityVector, fin);
```