# Binary Sort Tree won't compile

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program that creates a Binary Tree data structure but I'm getting these weird compiler errors:

```
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `BSTree::BSTree()'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x15): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `BSTree::BSTree()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't really have any experience with this sort of compiler error and can't really figure out what could be wrong. As far as I can tell I've written similar code for other projects which compile fine.

This is my code:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "BSTree.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    BSTree treeValues;
    return 0;
}
```

BSTree.h

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "BTNode.h"
using namespace std;
class BSTree
{
    public:
    BSTree();
    void add(int);
    private:
    BTNode* m_root;
    int m_size;
};
```

BSTree.cpp

```
BSTree::BSTree()
{
    m_root = NULL;
    m_size = 0;
}
void BSTree::add(int it)
{
    m_root = new BTNode(it);
}
```

BTNode.h

```
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
class BTNode
{
    public:
    BTNode(int);
    private:
    int m_data;
    BTNode* m_left;
    BTNode* m_right;
    BTNode* m_parent;
};
```

BTNode.cpp

```
BTNode::BTNode(int data)
{
    m_data = data;
    m_left = NULL;
    m_right = NULL;
    m_parent = NULL;
}
```

EDIT: fixed error message and formatting on .cpp files

Comment: If the file you claim produces this problem is indeed `main.cpp` (as shown in the question), why does your error message claim some file, `TreeHashTableDemo.cpp`, which is *none* of the files shown here, as the culprit using an undefined symbol ?

Comment: What you post here is working. If you actually have `cpp` files for the tree then you need to link them to the main program.

Comment: I didn't indicate the cpp files correctly so I've added them to my original post. But I'm still getting the error.

Comment: If that's your entire code, you should be getting some compilation errors before that linker error.

Comment: This is my full code. I just get this weird compiler error but nothing explicit regarding line numbers etc.

Comment: compile the tree code and link it with the main file.

Comment: because it's **linking error** and not compiler error. Your code has been compiled properly. You need to show your compile command

Comment: What do you mean? I'm compiling them together?

Comment: Well, what compiler are you using -- and -- are you using an IDE or command line? (presume you are using an IDE, because if you had been using the command line -- it would be apparent what is wrong). Are you using VS Code, gcc, clang -- what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You shouldn't use `using namespace std;` in header files
2. You should add `#include "BTNode.h"` in `BTNode.cpp`
3. You should add `#include "BSTree.h"` in `BSTree.cpp`

Comment: this fixed it, thanks

Comment: Can you please extend your answer and link to some stackoverflow pages ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872373/why-is-including-using-namespace-into-a-header-file-a-bad-idea-in-c) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849457/using-namespace-in-c-headers)) and extend 2 and 3 why one should/have to do that.