# openCV 2.4.9 compilation error with CUDA 6.5

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, cuda, gpu

I am running an ubuntu 14.04 system with CUDA 6.5 installed. I am trying to use the gpu implementation of feature matching of OpenCV library and my openCV library version is 2.4.9. cmake .. is ok but when I want to make project it gives me errors like:

```
> /usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:432:29: error: ‘vector’ does
> not name a type  CV_EXPORTS void merge(const vector<GpuMat>& src,
> GpuMat& dst, Stream& stream = Stream::Null());
>                              ^ /usr/local/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:432:35: error: expected ‘,’ or
> ‘...’ before ‘<’ token  CV_EXPORTS void merge(const vector<GpuMat>&
> src, GpuMat& dst, Stream& stream = Stream::Null());
```

Could you please help me with this? Thanks...

Comment: Did you `#include <vector>` and `using std::vector;`?

Comment: thanks. Do you mean in my own code? Cause the error is in gpu.hpp..

Comment: Try compiling with CUDA off and see if the problem still occurs.  I know that's not what your after but it will help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Still error is the same.

Comment: We need to see the compiler invocation, and not just the error. *If* you are using *g++*, then it sounds like `gpu.hpp` is missing an include for `<vector>` or its not `using std::vector`.

Answer (score 6):

put 
using namespace std; before you include gpu.hpp

example

```
using namespace std;
#include <opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp>
```

this works for me

Comment: Using namespace std makes me sad, taking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152925/can-i-undo-the-effect-of-using-namespace-in-c into consideration ...